# MySQL insert once for each subquery result

Tags: mysql, loops

I want to execute a MYSQL query:

```
INSERT INTO taskattempts (taskID) VALUES (_);
```

which I want to execute multiple times, once for each result of the query:

```
SELECT id FROM tasks WHERE stageID = 1;
```

using the resultant id from the second query as the value of taskID in the first.

Is there any way to do this using a single MySQL query? A PHP loop running multiple queries seems dreadfully inefficient.

**EDIT **

I actually need to fill in multiple columns, two static and one with the subquery. I found that INSERT INTO taskattempts (stageAttemptID, taskID, complete) SELECT 0, id, 5 FROM tasks WHERE stageID = 5; works, but wonder whether this is kosher. Also, in the interest of knowledge, can you fill in different columns with different queries?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 INSERT INTO taskattempts (taskID) SELECT id FROM tasks WHERE stageID = 1;
```

(This is universally supported standard SQL).

In response to the second part of the question, you can freely mix constants and columns in the `SELECT` clause:

```
 INSERT INTO taskattempts (stateAttemptID, taskID, complete) 
    SELECT 0, id, 5 FROM tasks WHERE stageID = 1;
```

If your constants are strings, don't forget to quote them.  And remember, you can include a complex `SELECT` statement with `JOIN`s and aggregation if required.

Comment: Well that was simple. Though, in an effort to simplify my question, I've missed something. I actually need to fill in multiple columns, two static and one with the subquery. I found that INSERT INTO taskattempts (stageAttemptID, taskID, complete) SELECT 0, id, 5 FROM tasks WHERE stageID = 5; works, but wonder whether this is kosher. Also, in the interest of knowledge, can you fill in different columns with different queries?

Comment: @wyatt if u miss something in your question edit the question . dont use comments for extending the question.